# Why isn't my upstart service listed in service --status-all

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, service, upstart

I created a bunch of upstart jobs for my services that I'm running on an Ubuntu 12.04. I can successfully start them and stop with with:

```
service my_service start
service my_service stop
```

but they are not listed when I do

```
service --status-all
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

To created the services I just added .conf files in /etc/init.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`service --status-all` only shows the services started using a script in `/etc/init.d/`. To list upstart jobs, do `initctl list`.

Comment: Thanks. I find it terrible odd that service blah start would start blah, and service --status-all wouldn't show its status. Oh well.